# How to open an EPUB inside of a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to open an epub file in my chrome extension page ('dist/epub-viewer.html') but chrome keeps trying to download the epub instead. I am using manifest v3.

```
function isEpubUrl(url) {
  return url.toLowerCase().endsWith('.epub');
}

function isEpubViewerUrl(url) {
  const viewerUrl = chrome.runtime.getURL('dist/epub-viewer.html');
  return url.startsWith(viewerUrl);
}

function openEpubInViewer(tabId, epubUrl) {
  const viewerUrl = chrome.runtime.getURL('dist/epub-viewer.html') + '?file=' + encodeURIComponent(epubUrl);
  chrome.tabs.update(tabId, { url: viewerUrl });
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.url && isEpubUrl(changeInfo.url) && !isEpubViewerUrl(tab.url)) {
    openEpubInViewer(tabId, changeInfo.url);
  }
});
```

Is there any way to do this without having to create an additional page where the user can open their EPUB? I have similar code for PDFs which works fine, but for EPUBs chrome keeps trying to download them.

Comment: You should be able to create a policy to handle certain file extensions.

Comment: You need to use [declarativeNetRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/) with `"regexFilter": "^.+?\\.epub$"` to redirect to your epub-viewer.html as shown [here](/a/73392754). You may also need to set Content-Disposition header to `inline` for these urls or remove this header altogether.